# Django can't see environment variables?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run Django (1.10) but getting an error:

```
(.venv)$ ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  ...
  File "/home/myapp/myapp/myapp/myapp/settings/local.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/home/myapp/myapp/myapp/myapp/settings/base.py", line 64, in <module>
    'NAME': utils.get_env_setting('RETR_DB_NAME'),
  File "/home/myapp/myapp/myapp/common/utils.py", line 13, in get_env_setting
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the RETR_DB_NAME env variable
```

But the environment variable is set:

```
(.venv) $ echo $RETR_DB_NAME
myname
```

The code in question looks like this:

```
def get_env_setting(setting):
  """ Get the environment setting or return exception """
  try:
    return environ[setting]
  except KeyError:
    error_msg = "Set the %s env variable" % setting
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
 ...
'NAME': utils.get_env_setting('RETR_DB_NAME'),
```

How come I can see the environment variable, but Django can't?

Comment: Have you tried `os.environ[setting]` instead of `environ[setting]` ?

Comment: Try running ``export RETR_DB_NAME`` in your shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odds are you forgot to `export` it. You can check if that's the problem with:

```
export -p | fgrep RETR_DB_NAME
```

which will output nothing if you forgot to `export`, and `export` can be used to make it exported (whether or not it was already exported, it's not an error to `export` twice) with:

```
export RETR_DB_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I recommend getting the variable using [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv) which allows you to return a default value.

Anyway make sure the environment variable is set using `export RETR_DB_NAME='db_name'` instead of `RETR_DB_NAME='db_name'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using shells like zsh, make sure to put `export key=value` in the config, e.g. ~/.zshrc.